# Angular input event firing only in IE

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, angular-material

The `institutionOnChange` input event is only firing in IE11 and not in Chrome The form control is being initialized in `ngOnInit`

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput required #instititionInput [matAutocomplete]="auto"
      [formControl]="form.get('institution')"
      (input)="institutionOnChange($event)"
      i18n-placeholder placeholder="Institution of Incident"
      i18n-aria-label aria-label="Institution of Incident">

  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let institution of filteredInstitutions | async"
        [value]="institution" (onSelectionChange)="institutionSelectionChange($event)">
      {{institution.name}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>

  <mat-hint *ngIf="form.get('institutionId').hasError('required')" i18n>
    <span class="mat-error">Please choose a institution</span>
  </mat-hint>
</mat-form-field>
```

The problem is in clearing another value on change until a item is selected

```js
institutionOnChange(event) {
  this.form.get('institutionId').setValue('');
}

public ngOnInit() {
  ...
  if (institutionId) {

    const foundInstitution = this.institutions.find(institution => institution.id === institutionId);

    if (foundInstitution) {
      this.form.get('institution').setValue(foundInstitution);
      this.form.get('institutionId').setValue(institutionId);
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Please add more detail to your question to explain exactly what your problem is. Also creating a [SlackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/) of your problem may help to get it resolved faster.

Comment: What is unclear about the issue?

Comment: what is `form`? I cannot see a form tag in your html, or it being defined/initialised in your ts